# Is it possible to let SlideInMenu of react-native-popup-menu slide in from the right or left?

Tags: react-native-popup-menu

Standard Behaviour for react-native-popup-menu SlideInMenu renderer is to slide in from the bottom and slide out towards it again. Can this be changed to left or right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it is quite easy. You can just edit the

```
  transform: [{
    translateY: this.state.slide.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [oHeight, 0]
    }),
  }]
```

in SlideInMenu.js and change the translateY to translateX. Or if you want to change directions accordingly change the values.

I added a dynamic SlideInMenuDirection.js now for all my needs and registered it in the index.js.